# Change battery level in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Can i change battery level in windows phone 8 in emulator.I want simulate Resource-intensive task is not work under %90.Can i set battery level for windows phone emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to organically activate ResourceIntensiveBackgroundTasks in the WP8 emulator. If you're trying to activate it for testing purposes I'd use [ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest("myService")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method instead.

As you mentioned, ResourceIntensiveBackgroundAgents don't run on devices with less then 90% full charge as stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforResourceintensiveAgents).

> Resource-intensive agents do not run unless the device’s battery power
>   is greater than 90%.

If you want to real-world test that for whatever reason, it's best to do that on a real device.